# Using custom css class as a value in css file

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have custom color class "bg-primary" which I'm using it in class attribute to change color

```html
<a class="btn btn-link bg-primary>Some Text</a>"
```

But I would like to use it as a value in css properties for example like this (it doesnt work):

```html
color: var(--bg-primary)
```

the goal is to change the color of the text and not the whole html element

Is it possible to do ? or may be there is some work around ?

my "bg-primary" class in different cases will use different colors and that's why I need to stick to that variable

Comment: May be all more HTML - Do you have other `bg-primary` class in your HTML or just that one ? You want to color one only with `var`

Comment: no its the only one, I'm using it for multiple elements and I would like to color text only with this color yes with var or somehow else

Comment: Hi, Is do you want to assign the color value for a variable and then use that variable in CSS? like : var testcolor :#12345 and in css class .bg-primary{color:testcolor}

Comment: I want to use that testcolor value in some other css class. I do not need to assign a new value I just want to use like it is